# save PyMC3 traceplot subplots to image file

Tags: python, matplotlib, pymc3

I am trying very simply to plot subplots generated by the PyMC3 traceplot function (see [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/plots.py)) to a file.

The function generates a numpy.ndarray (2d) of subplots.

I need to move or copy these subplots into a matplotlib.figure in order to save the image file. Everything I can find shows how to generate the figure's subplots **first**, then build them out.

As a minimum example, I lifted the sample PyMC3 code from [Here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/examples/disaster_model_arbitrary_deterministic.py), and added to it just a few lines in an attempt to handle the subplots.

```
from pymc3 import *
import theano.tensor as tt
from theano import as_op
from numpy import arange, array, empty

### Added these three lines relative to source #######################
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

__all__ = ['disasters_data', 'switchpoint', 'early_mean', 'late_mean', 'rate', 'disasters']

# Time series of recorded coal mining disasters in the UK from 1851 to 1962
disasters_data = array([4, 5, 4, 0, 1, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 3, 3, 4, 0, 2, 6,
                        3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 2, 5,
                        2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0,
                        1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1,
                        0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2,
                        3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 4,
                        0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
years = len(disasters_data)

@as_op(itypes=[tt.lscalar, tt.dscalar, tt.dscalar], otypes=[tt.dvector])
def rateFunc(switchpoint, early_mean, late_mean):
    out = empty(years)
    out[:switchpoint] = early_mean
    out[switchpoint:] = late_mean
    return out


with Model() as model:

    # Prior for distribution of switchpoint location
    switchpoint = DiscreteUniform('switchpoint', lower=0, upper=years)
    # Priors for pre- and post-switch mean number of disasters
    early_mean = Exponential('early_mean', lam=1.)
    late_mean = Exponential('late_mean', lam=1.)

    # Allocate appropriate Poisson rates to years before and after current switchpoint location
    rate = rateFunc(switchpoint, early_mean, late_mean)

    # Data likelihood
    disasters = Poisson('disasters', rate, observed=disasters_data)

    # Initial values for stochastic nodes
    start = {'early_mean': 2., 'late_mean': 3.}

    # Use slice sampler for means
    step1 = Slice([early_mean, late_mean])
    # Use Metropolis for switchpoint, since it accomodates discrete variables
    step2 = Metropolis([switchpoint])

    # njobs>1 works only with most recent (mid August 2014) Thenao version:
    # https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/2021
    tr = sample(1000, tune=500, start=start, step=[step1, step2], njobs=1)

    ### gnashing of teeth starts here ################################
    fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3,2)

    # This gives a KeyError
    # axarr = traceplot(tr, axarr)

    # This finishes without error
    trarr = traceplot(tr)

    # doesn't work
    # axarr[0, 0] = trarr[0, 0]

    fig.savefig("disaster.png")
```

I've tried a few variations along the subplot() and add_subplot() lines, to no avail -- all errors point toward the fact that empty subplots must first be created for the figure, not assigned to pre-existing subplots.

A different example (see [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter1_Introduction/Ch1_Introduction_PyMC3.ipynb), about 80% of the way down, beginning with

```
### Mysterious code to be explained in Chapter 3.
```

) avoids the utility altogether and builds out the subplots manually, so maybe there's no good answer to this? Is the pymc3.traceplot output indeed an orphaned ndarray of subplots that can't be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can you print `type(trarr[0,0])` and post the result?*

First of all, matplotlib axes objects are part of a figure and can only live inside a figure. It is therefore not possible to simply take an axes and put it to a different figure. However, in your case it **may** be, that `fig.add_axes(trarr[0,0])` nonetheless works. I doubt it, but you can still try.

Apart from that, [`traceplot()`](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/api.html#pymc3.plots.traceplot) has a keyword argument called `ax`.

> ax : axes
>       Matplotlib axes. Defaults to None.

Although it is pretty unclear, how you'd specify several subplots as one axes object, you can still try to play around with it. Try to put a single axes in or your own created subplots axes array `axarr` or only part of it.

**Edit**, just that noone oversees the small line in the comments:
According to the answer in the [bug report](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/1577), `traceplot(tr, ax = axarr)` is indeed reported to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. the `type(trarr[0,0])`  is <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>. I tried the `fig.add_axes(...)` suggestion, and got similar error to earlier -- axes need to already exist in the fig. I had also played around with feeding the pre-constructed numpy.ndarray of subplots into the traceplot function, but that generates a whole different thread of errors [bug report here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/1577).

Comment: EDIT: if one remembers to use the keywork for the argument `traceplot(tr, ax = axarr)`, it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem. I am working with `pymc3` 3.5 and `matplotlib` 2.1.2.

I realized it's possible to export the traceplot by:

```
trarr = traceplot(tr)

fig = plt.gcf() # to get the current figure...
fig.savefig("disaster.png") # and save it directly
```